# Swing only reads the first character of my AbstractDocument.Content. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, swing, document, large-files

I have a feature in the works where I'm supposed to display a giant text file. So I figured I would try memory mapping a file on disk once it exceeds a certain size.

The text is immutable at least, which should be easier than having to write a full editor which supports the same kind of sizes.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class CharBufferContent implements AbstractDocument.Content {
    private final CharBuffer charBuffer;
    private final int length;

    public CharBufferContent(CharBuffer charBuffer) {
        this.charBuffer = charBuffer;
        length = charBuffer.length();
    }

    public Position createPosition(int offset) throws BadLocationException {
        return new ImmutablePosition(offset);
    }

    public int length() {
        return length;
    }

    public UndoableEdit insertString(int where, String string)
            throws BadLocationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Document is immutable");
    }

    public UndoableEdit remove(int where, int nItems) throws BadLocationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Document is immutable");
    }

    public String getString(int where, int length) throws BadLocationException {
        if (where < 0 || where + length > this.length) {
            throw new BadLocationException("Invalid range", this.length);
        }

        char[] out = new char[length];
        charBuffer.position(where);
        charBuffer.get(out);
        return new String(out);
    }

    public void getChars(int where, int length, Segment segment)
            throws BadLocationException {
        if (where < 0 || where + length > this.length) {
            throw new BadLocationException("Invalid range", this.length);
        }

        // This will be inefficient, but I'm just trying to get it working first.
        segment.array = new char[length];
        charBuffer.position(where);
        charBuffer.get(segment.array, 0, length);
        segment.offset = 0;
        segment.count = length;
    }

    private static class ImmutablePosition implements Position {
        private final int offset;

        private ImmutablePosition(int offset) {
            this.offset = offset;
        }

        @Override
        public int getOffset() {
            return offset;
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a little test program which just uses an in-memory buffer to test it:

```
public class Test implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Test());
    }

    public void run() {
        CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap("This is a fairly simple test, " +
            "so nothing should go wrong, right?\n");
        AbstractDocument.Content content = new CharBufferContent(charBuffer);
        final Document document = new PlainDocument(content);

        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(document);
        text.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane textScroll = new JScrollPane(text);
        textScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(textScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I run it, the window displays "T". In the debugger, I can see that Swing is only calling `length()` and `getChars()`. Every call to `getChars()` has `where == 0` and `length == 1`. So it makes sense that it would only have one character to display, but it seems odd that Swing would be calling my code and only ever asking for the first character, even though I can see that `length()` returns the full length of the text.

When I run the same test with a StringContent as the implementation, `getChars()` in that is called with the full length of the document.

There isn't a lot in this API which looks like it could go wrong, so I'm baffled.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not well versed in the Document API, but my understanding is that an `AbstractDocument.Content` is not expected to come pre-equipped with its own text. AbstractDocument doesn't know what to do in that case. If you try this with a StringContent, you'll see the same problem:

```
content = new StringContent();
content.insertString(0, "some text");
final AbstractDocument document = new PlainDocument(content);
```

This only displays the leading 's'. Apparently, AbstractDocument models an extra valid position at the end of the document for the caret, and it expects its Content to have a length +1 its actual length to support this, which I believe is the origin of the fact that the first character does appear.

If you call `StringContent.insertString` just *after* creating the document, it seems to work in that it displays all the text, but I think that might just be luck. If the string inserted this way contains line breaks, it will always ignore them because they are not modeled as separate Document Elements as they're required to be.

I think the only way to make this work is to implement Document directly, rather than AbstractDocument.Content. It's a more complicated interface but this does work:

```
class CharBufferDocument implements Document {
    private final CharBuffer charBuffer;
    private final int length;
    private final int[] lineOffsets;

    public CharBufferDocument(CharBuffer charBuffer) {
        this.charBuffer = charBuffer;

        charBuffer.position(0);
        length = charBuffer.length();

        int[] lineOffsets = new int[] { 0 };
        int lineCount = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char c = charBuffer.get(i);
            if (c == '\n') {
                if (lineCount == lineOffsets.length) {
                    if (lineCount == Integer.MAX_VALUE) throw new OutOfMemoryError();
                    int newLength = (int)Math.min(lineCount * 2L, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                    lineOffsets = Arrays.copyOf(lineOffsets, newLength);
                }
                lineOffsets[lineCount++] = i + 1;
            }
        }

        lineOffsets = Arrays.copyOf(lineOffsets, lineCount);
        this.lineOffsets = lineOffsets;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    @Override
    public void addDocumentListener(DocumentListener listener) {}

    @Override
    public void removeDocumentListener(DocumentListener listener) {}

    @Override
    public void addUndoableEditListener(UndoableEditListener listener) {}

    @Override
    public void removeUndoableEditListener(UndoableEditListener listener) {}

    @Override
    public void putProperty(Object key, Object value) {}

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(Object key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int offs, int len) throws BadLocationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Document is immutable");
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Document is immutable");
    }

    @Override
    public String getText(int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
        char[] out = new char[length];
        charBuffer.position(offset);
        charBuffer.get(out);
        return new String(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void getText(int offset, int length, Segment segment) throws BadLocationException {
        segment.array = new char[length];
        charBuffer.position(offset);
        charBuffer.get(segment.array);
        segment.offset = 0;
        segment.count = length;
    }

    @Override
    public Position getStartPosition() {
        return createPosition(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Position getEndPosition() {
        return createPosition(getLength());
    }

    @Override
    public Position createPosition(int offset) {
        return new ImmutablePosition(offset);
    }

    private final Element rootElement = new Element() {
        @Override
        public Document getDocument() {
            return CharBufferDocument.this;
        }

        @Override
        public Element getParentElement() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "root";
        }

        @Override
        public AttributeSet getAttributes() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getStartOffset() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getEndOffset() {
            return getLength();
        }

        @Override
        public int getElementIndex(int offset) {
            // binary search for the line that contains offset
            int low = 0;
            int high = lineOffsets.length - 1;

            while (low <= high) {
                int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
                int midLineStart = lineOffsets[mid];
                int midLineEnd = (mid + 1 < lineOffsets.length) ? (lineOffsets[mid + 1] - 1) : getLength();

                if (offset < midLineStart) {
                    high = mid - 1;
                } else if (offset > midLineEnd) {
                    low = mid + 1;
                } else {
                    return mid;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getElementCount() {
            return lineOffsets.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Element getElement(int index) {
            return createLineElement(
                lineOffsets[index],
                (index + 1 < lineOffsets.length) ? (lineOffsets[index + 1] - 1) : getLength()
            );
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf() {
            return false;
        }
    };

    private Element createLineElement(final int start, final int end) {
        return new Element() {
            @Override
            public Document getDocument() {
                return CharBufferDocument.this;
            }

            @Override
            public Element getParentElement() {
                return CharBufferDocument.this.getDefaultRootElement();
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "line"; // XXX: Does the name matter?
            }

            @Override
            public AttributeSet getAttributes() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getStartOffset() {
                return start;
            }

            @Override
            public int getEndOffset() {
                return end;
            }

            @Override
            public int getElementIndex(int offset) {
                return -1;
            }

            @Override
            public int getElementCount() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Element getElement(int index) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLeaf() {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Element getDefaultRootElement() {
        return rootElement;
    }

    @Override
    public Element[] getRootElements() {
        return new Element[] { getDefaultRootElement() };
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Runnable r) {
        r.run();
    }

    private static class ImmutablePosition implements Position {
        private final int offset;

        private ImmutablePosition(int offset) {
            this.offset = offset;
        }

        @Override
        public int getOffset() {
            return offset;
        }
    }
}
```